# R, delete string of text or numbers using R

Tags: r

I have 300 text files containing addresses with post codes. I need to write a code in R that scan these files and remove 6 digits letter/numbers after the postcode word.

example:

Postcode WD11 9ZP  to  Postcode XXXX XXX.

Thank you!

Comment: What should be the expected output from the example above

Comment: I suggest you to read SO guidelines about good asking: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.
I didn't see your code attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can just remove all but the first two letters that make up the postcode word? E.g. so:

```
postcodes <- "WD11 9ZP"
gsub("(^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}).*", "\\1", postcodes, perl = TRUE)

[1] "WD"
```

Could also use

```
substr(postcodes, 1, 2)
```